# How to get first element of array in php using key and how to find first key of array

Tags: php

How to get **first element** of array in php using key and how to find first key of array?

Comment: Can you please provide code.

Comment: post what you tried? and what issues you faced

Comment: you can use key($array)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
$key = array_shift(array_keys($yourArray));
echo $yourArray[$key];
```